# Tooltip behavior on line chart with Date as the x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a line chart with a tooltip where the x-axis is a date.

I would like the line and tooltip to change after it is halfway (or similar) to the next tick on the x-axis.

Mainly I would like the behavior to be the same as this bl.ock: http://bl.ocks.org/wdickerson/64535aff478e8a9fd9d9facccfef8929

You can view the behavior I currently have on my bl.ock: https://bl.ocks.org/JulienAssouline/574a52ee2034bcdc1e56ed926f36dd52

It mostly works but the data only changes after it passes to the September month and it never reaches the October month.

I have tried to adapt my code to the bl.ock. The problem is the bl.ock displayed is using years and I am using a date format which seems to be my main problem.

Here is the main part of the code:

```
 var tipBox = svg.append("rect")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height)
              .attr("opacity", 0)
              .on("mousemove", drawTooltip)
              .on("mouseout", removeTooltip)

                function removeTooltip() {
                if (tooltip) tooltip.style('display', 'none');
                if (tooltipLine) tooltipLine.attr('stroke', 'none');
              }

              function drawTooltip(){
                const line_hover = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
                // console.log(d3.mouse(this)[0])
                 console.log(xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]).getMonth())

                  console.log(Math.floor(xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0])))

                   const date_hover = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]).getMonth()



                 // yScale.invert(pos.y)

                tooltipLine.attr("stroke", "grey")
                  .attr("x1", xScale(line_hover))
                  .attr("x2", xScale(line_hover))
                  .attr("y1", 0)
                  .attr("y2", height)
                  .attr("class", "line_hover")
                  .style('stroke-width', 1)

                  tooltip.html(date_hover)
                      .style("position", "absolute")
                      .style("background-color", "lightgrey")
                      .style('display', 'block')
                      .style('left', d3.event.pageX - 100+ "px")
                      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 20+"px")
                      .selectAll()
                      .data(dataNest).enter()
                      .append('div')
                      .style('color', "black")
                      .html(function(e){ return e.key + ': ' + e.values.find(function(h){ return (h.Date.getMonth() + 0.5) == (date_hover + 0.5) }).randNumCol})
              }
```

You can again view all of the code on my bl.ock: https://bl.ocks.org/JulienAssouline/574a52ee2034bcdc1e56ed926f36dd52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetMonth will always give the month. Get the date and display based on the date. Not ideal, but works.
Example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/UmeshMaharshi30/d0b80d4a2e49f68b2308463d4b9e20c7)